# When getting element by ID, how can I grab the contents within the section?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In javascript when I call the "getElementById" method, how can I access the information within that ID section, such as a link for example?

```
<p id="demo"><a href="someWebsite.com">some link</a></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Grab Link</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var thisLink = document.getElementById("demo");
        thisLink.(functionToGetSomeLink); //any way to get the link???
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the `a` as a node or are you trying to get the html within `demo` or are you trying to get the href of the link? Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to access the href within the paragraph tag marked with id "demo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can chain another method onto document.getElementById("demo"); such as:

document.getElementById("demo").value

or

document.getElementById("demo").text

Answer (score 0):

Use

**querySelector**

to access the anchor

```
var anchorTag = document.querySelector('#demo a');

var href = anchorTag.getAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if I didn't understand the question correctly.

You can just get the first (only) child of the #demo div and get the `href` attribute. This example only uses a couple lines but it is possible to further simplify it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var thisLink = document.getElementById("demo").children[0].href;
  alert(thisLink);
  console.log(thisLink);
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"><a href="someWebsite.com">some link</a>
</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Grab Link</button>
```